# WebApi return HTTP status code 400, 401 etc without ActionResult

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, webapi

Is it possible to return a specific http status if the method does not return an ActionResult?

Example in:

```
public async Task<IQueryable<ModuleView>> Get()
```

I can't return ActionResult<IQueryable> because ActionResult not worked with OData and EnableQueryAttribute, Attribute was not fired... In attribute I have:

```
override IQueryable ApplyQuery(IQueryable queryable, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
```

But I Want to return BadRequest, Unauthorized etc...

It is possible?

Edit:
I have .net 6 web api with OData 8.0.10.

I'Am trying something like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IQueryable<ModuleView>>> Get(ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
    {
        return Ok(SetQueryOptions(_ModuleViewRepository.GetModuleViewData(userSession.OperatorActivities), queryOptions));
    }

    private IQueryable<T> SetQueryOptions<T>(IQueryable<T> data, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions) where T : class
    {
        return (IQueryable<T>)queryOptions.ApplyTo(data, new ODataQuerySettings { PageSize = 10 });
    }
```

But I have an error:

```
Cannot create an EDM model as the action 'Get' on controller 'Module' has a return type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult`1[[System.Linq.IQueryable`1[[DataBase.Models.DBObject.View.ModuleView, DataBase, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Linq.Expressions, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]], Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]]' that does not implement IEnumerable<T>.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `IHttpActionResult` and in return you can use `Ok()` and in this mthod you can pass a JSON data this method is come from IHttpActionResult class

something like this:

```
  public IHttpActionResult GetStudent()
        {
            var StudentDtos = _context.Students.ToList();
            return Ok(StudentDtos);
        }
```

there are so many return methods you can use for `IHttpActionResult` class
also you can apply HTTPS methods above these API methods

like this

```
[HttpDelete]
        public IHttpActionResult DeleteStudent(int id)
        {
            var student = _context.Students.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);
            if (student == null)
                return NotFound();

            _context.Students.Remove(student);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return Ok();
        }
```

Comment: "The type or namespace name 'IHttpActionResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"
I know that I cna use ActionResult or IActionResult, But then, as I wrote, the EnableQueryAttribute argument does not work. Arg are not firing... because have override method override IQueryable ApplyQuery(IQueryable queryable, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)

Comment: `using System.Web.Http;` use this in namespace and inherit your class with ApiController this Controller can hanlde your HTTPS request

Comment: With [ApiController] OData endpoint not working...